# PHP vs Javascript For Iteration

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Ok so i'm trying to count IP. I have a PHP version and a JQuery/Javascript version. PHP works a dream, except for not outputting to screen until the PHP script has finished but i'm ok with that. The issue I'm having is with the jquery/javascript version. Counting the 4th Octet is fine but when it comes to counting the 3rd Octet i'm having a strange issue.

Basically if my range is 10.211.55.254 - 10.211.56.2, i'm good. But if i was to increase to 10.211.56.3 or above ip addresses i get the following results:

```
10.211.55.250
10.211.56.250
```

This only happens if increase, reducing to below 10.211.55.254 still works.

So here are the scripts from each, where i'm i going wrong/missing on the Javascript?

```
The Javascript

var startiparrayslice = startiparray.slice( 0, 2);

for ( var octet3 = startiparray[2] ; octet3 <= endiparray[2]; octet3++) {
    var pingip2 = startiparrayslice.join(".") + "." + octet3;

    if (startiparray[3] > endiparray[3]) {
        endiparrayorig = endiparray[3];
        endiparray[3] = 255;

    }


for ( var octet4 = startiparray[3] ; octet4 <= endiparray[3]; octet4++) {

    if (octet4 == endiparray[3]) {
        startiparray[3] = 0;
        endiparray[3] = endiparrayorig;

    }

    var pingip = pingip2 + "." + octet4; 

    $.post("ping-query-process.php", {  
        pingformip:pingip
    },
```

.

```
The PHP

$ipnetwork = array_slice($iprangestartex,0,2);
    $ip = implode(".",$ipnetwork);

    for ($octet3=$iprangestartex[2];$octet3<=$iprangeendex[2];$octet3++) {

        $ipaddress = $ip . "." . $octet3;

        if ($iprangestartex[3] > $iprangeendex[3]) {
            $iprangeendexorig = $iprangeendex[3];
            $iprangeendex[3] = "255";
        }

        for ($octet4=$iprangestartex[3];$octet4<=$iprangeendex[3];$octet4++) {

            if ($octet4 == $iprangeendex[3]) {
                $iprangestartex[3] = "0";
                $iprangeendex[3] = $iprangeendexorig;
            }

            $ipaddress4 = $ipaddress . "." . $octet4;
            $pingresult = exec("/bin/ping -c 1 $ipaddress4", $result, $status);

                if (0 == $status) {
                    $status = "alive";
                } else {
                    $status = "dead";
                }

                echo "The IP Address, $ipaddress4, is ".$status."<br /><br />";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok further testing has shown this only applies to IPs from 10.211.56.3-9. For example if i ping 10.211.55.254 - 10.211.56.2 it works. if i ping 10.211.55.254 - 10.211.56.3-9 it fails and if i ping 10.211.55.254 - 10.211.56.10 it works.... More confused.

Comment: Further testing looks like it is unable to do the comparison in the first IF statement if the the end ip between 3 - 9.

Comment: Can you give us an example array, so we can run it for ourselves?

Comment: There are two arrays 1, startiparray[10,211,55,254] and 2, endiparray[10,211,56,3] for example. I have used an example that doesn't work for me!

Answer (score 1):

Well I didn't see that one coming!! After testing testing testing and using plenty of alert boxes I narrowed it down to the fact that the array1[3] wasn't comparing to array2[3] for certain numbers. Don't ask me why only on certain numbers because I do not know (Answers on a postcard please).

I was able see that the array was trying to compare strings using array2[3].constructor when in actual fact what i needed to compare numbers. So to achieve this I included the following parseInt

```
if (parseInt(startiparray[3]) > parseInt(endiparray[3])) { }
```

This compared the array elements as numbers and I was able to iterate through 3-9 where before it would failover.

I would still like to understand why... As i'm new to development this is a sharp learning curve.

Thanks